# Unable to extract ids from urls

Tags: excel, vba, split

I'm trying to split some urls to get the ids located at the rightmost portion of each url. In other languages there are reverse indexing options, as in `[-1]` to split up the last portion. However, I'm struggling to find out any such option in vba to do the trick. Please consider this attempt `Split(linkId, "/")(1)` as a placeholder.

***How can I grab the ids located at the rightmost portion of different urls?***

My attempt so far:

```
Sub GetId()
    Dim linkId As Variant, linkList As Variant

    linkList = Array( _
        "https://etc.com/en/category/all/all/shops/206898", _
        "https://etc.com/ar/category/all/mobile/350689", _
        "https://etc.com/bn/category/all/bike/760689" _
        )


    For Each linkId In linkList
        Debug.Print Split(linkId, "/")(1)
    Next linkId
End Sub
```

Expected output:

```
206898
350689
760689
```

Post script: ids may not be of same length always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub GetId()
    Dim linkId As Variant, linkList As Variant, v As Variant

    linkList = Array( _
        "https://etc.com/en/category/all/all/shops/206898", _
        "https://etc.com/ar/category/all/mobile/350689", _
        "https://etc.com/bn/category/all/bike/760689" _
        )

    For Each linkId In linkList
        v = Split(linkId, "/")
        Debug.Print v(UBound(v))
    Next linkId
End Sub
```

Comment: Vote for you. That's one of the (many) functions that never comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

You want the index of the right-most slash. `InStr` can get you the index of a character starting from the left, but what you want is `InStrRev`, to get the index of a character starting from the right.

Using that index, the `Mid` function gets you the substring you're after - this code produces the desired output:

```
Debug.Print Mid(linkId, InStrRev(linkId, "/") + 1)
```

No need to `Split` the string and involve array manipulations, string functions can handle that natively.

Note that `For Each` is efficient for iteration object collections. To iterate arrays, use a `For` loop for optimal performance<sup>[[Source]](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/)</sup>.

Moreover, working with `String` instead of `Variant` avoids implicit type conversions. Hence, this should be more efficient:

```
Sub GetId()
    Dim linkList As Variant
    linkList = Array( _
        "https://etc.com/en/category/all/all/shops/206898", _
        "https://etc.com/ar/category/all/mobile/350689", _
        "https://etc.com/bn/category/all/bike/760689" _
        )
    Dim current As Long, link As String
    For current = LBound(linkList) To UBound(linkList)
        link = linkList(current)
        Debug.Print Mid$(link, InStrRev(link, "/") + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is what I most of the time prefer to go with @Mathieu Guindon. I wish I could accept both the answers. Btw, is it good to go as well `Split(StrReverse(link), "/")(0)`? Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt Should work if you reverse it back after but why? You are now chaining two reverses and a split which all have to allocate and create new strings. I would expect that to be both less readable and less efficient. On your small scale maybe the efficiency won't matter but I still wouldn't recommend that route.